# About int.class

Tags: java, class, object, int

i have been experimenting with java trying to logically understanding it ...
but i dont understand why this makes sense in java

```
int.class
```

i mean int is not a class.it's just a primitive type;so as far as i can understand it contains a number and nothing more.. let alone a "class" element inside it ...
what is happening in the background ?How is this possible?
please be as more as more elaborate as you can.
thank you in advance.

P.S. i read some of the other answers to similarly asked questions ..but i didn't understand.

Comment: What part of "`int.class`is `Class<Integer>`" didn't you understand?

Comment: so it's implicitly converted to Class<Integer>

Answer (score -3):

Variables of the primitive types hold primitive values, and variables of the reference type hold reference values. Reference values refer to objects, but are not objects themselves. Primitive values, by contrast, do not refer to anything. They are the actual data themselves.

Comment: This answer nothing to do with the OP.